# Error while integrating CKFinder with CKEditor

Tags: php, xampp, ckeditor, ckfinder

i am new in web development with PHP, while integrating ckfinder with ckeditor, when i am uploading image to server i am getiing a error -> The PHP installation does not meet the minimum system requirements for CKFinder. Missing PHP extensions: GD. Please refer to CKFinder documentation for more details

Does anybody know how to solve it ?

I am using XAMPP on Windows

Comment: Install php-gd?

Comment: Linux? or Windows? or other??

Comment: @RiggsFolly windows

Comment: Manually installed or WAMPServer or XAMPP or other

Comment: @RiggsFolly XAMPP

Comment: edit `php.ini` and remove the `;` which is a comment marker from the `extension=gd` line

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hey, Thanks buddy. It started working.